# Can I develop a OneNote JS-based add-in for OneMac for Mac?

Tags: office-js

The new Javascript-based API for add-ins seems to have a DOM for OneNote, and I can see the option to install add-ins in the OneNote web app. Would I be able to load a JS-based add-in in OneNote for Mac as well? I couldn't find anything in the menus of OneNote for Mac.
And how about OneNote for iOS? Would the add-in be installable as well?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, support for Office Web Add-ins in OneNote is currently limited to OneNote on the Web.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability